# Fill height in scrollView in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview, swift5

I am coding useing swiftUI and I have a vertical `scrollView` (see screenshots), and inside that `scrollView` I have another horizontal `scrollView`, and below that I have a `VStack` that I want the height to fill the rest of the screen to the bottom of the vertical `scrollView`, but I can't seem to make it work.

The content in the vertical `scrollView` can be larger than the actually remaining space in some cases that is why I need a scrollView, but in some other cases the content is smaller than the remaining space

Here is the code I have :

```
    VStack {
        HeaderView
        
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            FriendsHorizontalScrollView()
            
            VStack {
                // I want this view to take all the remaining height left in the scrollView
                FullHeightView()
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        }
    }
```

What I end up having is something like this :

[image]

What I want to have :

[image]

I have tried several solutions like using geometryReader or putting `.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)` on the `VStack` but nothing seems to work properly.

Comment: Why do you need vertical scroll view then?

Comment: I edited the post, the content can be larger in some cases that is why I need a scrollView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible approach based on view preferences (`ViewHeightKey` is taken from my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62358846/foreach-and-geometryreader-variable-height-for-children/62561752?r=SearchResults&s=9%7C16.2992#62561752) solution. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoLayoutInScrollView: View {
    @State private var height1: CGFloat = .zero
    @State private var height2: CGFloat = .zero
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            HeaderView()

            GeometryReader { gp in
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        FriendsHorizontalScrollView()
                            .background(GeometryReader {
                                Color.clear
                                    .preference(key: ViewHeightKey.self, value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height)
                            })
                            .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) { self.height1 = $0 }
                        VStack(spacing: 0) {
                            // I want this view to take all the remaining height left in the scrollView
                            FullHeightView()
                                .background(GeometryReader {
                                    Color.clear
                                        .preference(key: ViewHeightKey.self, value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height)
                                })
                        }.frame(height: max(gp.size.height - self.height1, self.height2))
                        .background(Color.yellow)
                    }
                }
                .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) { self.height2 = $0 }
            }
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}
```

replicated helper views (for testing)

```
struct FriendsHorizontalScrollView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Horizontal Scroller")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height: 100)
            .background(Color.green)
    }
}

struct FullHeightView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
            Text("Dynamic Content")
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .frame(height: 300)
    }
}

struct HeaderView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle().foregroundColor(.blue)
            .frame(height: 60)
            .overlay(Text("Header"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 43):

This can be achieved by using `GeometryReader`. The idea is to set `minHeight` of your root view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Text("View 1")
                        .frame(height: 100)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background(Color.green)
                    Text("View 2")
                        .frame(height: 100)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background(Color.gray)
                    VStack {
                        Text("VStack")
                        Text("View 3")
                            .frame(height: 100)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .padding()
                    }
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                }
                .frame(minHeight: proxy.size.height)
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer, better than the accepted one I think because it doesn't involve additional variables and redraws.

Comment: Brilliant approach! I knew what I wanted but couldn't think of the words to describe it, but thinking of this as the scrollable view having the screen height as its minimum height is very elegant and a great solution.