# SwiftUI: Read bounding rect of given String

Tags: fonts, swiftui

In UIKit it was relatively easy to calculate the needed size of a string with a given font.  How can I achieve this in SwiftUI?

It seems in SwiftUI, the needed properties on `Text` and `Font` to do the calculation are missing.

Here's the code I have so far. The problem is I don't want to use a hard-coded Font or a `UIFont` at all.

```swift
private func determineTruncation(_ geometry: GeometryProxy) {

    // Calculate the bounding box we'd need to render the
    // text given the width from the GeometryReader.
    let total = text.boundingRect(
        with: CGSize(
            width: geometry.size.width,
            height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        ),
        options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
        attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)],
        context: nil
    )

    if total.size.height > geometry.size.height {
        self.truncated = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you show code where/why (what for) do you need that size? `Cause in majority of cases it is either not needed at all or achieved by different instruments.

Comment: I added the code I have so far

Comment: For the truth I don't see the reason of this code... Might be this [How to set relative width in a HStack embedded in a ForEach in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62993223/12299030) topic will be helpful for you as approach demo.

Comment: The reason I wrote this was: If my Text needs to much space I want to put it in a ScrollView. Otherwise not

Comment: In such case it is better to put it inside ScrollView, but disable scrolling if not needed to scroll. It is already solved in [SwiftUI: Make ScrollView scrollable only if it exceeds the height of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62466397/12299030)